# Calling one javascript function with another

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Ok, here's the basic idea. I want to have one javascript activate another. It seems like a fairly straightforward idea. I have my first js file set a variable to 1, and my second js file start with an if statement where if that variable equals 1 it fires. Unfortunately I can't for the life of me figure out how to create a JS variable that can be read and modified by both files. In an earlier post on the wordpress stack exchange site I read that you can do that by declaring a variable in wp_head. Unfortunately, while the functions.php file runs ok, I can't seem to access the variable I created. I've tried wp_head.variable, which isn't defined. I've tried just the variable name, which isn't defined. I've tried defining it, but that just creates a local version of that variable.

If there's an easier way to fire off the second script in response to the first please let me know. They need to be in different files because each file needs a different php variable localized. And yes, the actions of the first script are firing correctly.

functions.php snippet:

```
function my_js_variables(){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var activate = 0;
</script>
<?php
}

add_action ( 'wp_head', 'my_js_variables' );
```

First script:

```
jQuery('#grab').click(function()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: my_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
      data: ({action : 'get_my_option'}),
      datatype: "json",
      success: function(json){
      activate = 1;
      }
        })
      })
```

Second Script:

```
if (activate == 1)
{
      alert('so far so good');
};
```

Comment: You'll have to declare the variable *outside* the function.

Comment: Or put it on `window` - `window.activate = 1`. Note that using globals for synchronization, while a necessity sometimes is problematic and can create maintenance problems.

Comment: If it is javascript then its straight forward solution `global variables` , if it is between .php try setting it in `session`

Comment: There's no way this can work in its current state, even if you can get your PHP to correctly place the scripts on the page. The first script simply installs a `click` handler. The second script runs immediately after that, **skips** the `if` block because `activate` is still `0` (nothing has been clicked yet) and exits. When eventually the user clicks the `#grab` and your AJAX request completes, `activate` becomes `1`... but nothing else happens. The second script doesn't magically get re-run because `activate` changed, that wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the approach of triggering and binding to an event:

First script

```
jQuery('#grab').click(function()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: my_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
      data: ({action : 'get_my_option'}),
      datatype: "json",
      success: function(json){
        $(document).trigger('custom_event');
      }
    })
})
```

Second script

```
$(document).bind('custom_event', function() {
    alert('so far so good');
}
```